# Doubt on integrality gap and LP relaxation

Tags: approximation, algorithm-design, rounding

I have an exercise that tells me that, given a problem P (of which now I omit the description) there is no integrality gap between LP and ILP formulation of this problem, and for every fractional LP-solution, there exists an integral
feasible solution with the same cost. Then I have to design a poly-time algorithm that from any
given optimal LP-solution, computes such an optimal integer assignment.

The fact that there is integrality gap what does it mean in this case? I mean, if I design an approximation-algorithm to compute an optimal integer assignment from a given optimal LP-solution, I will get a solution with object value like *something*  *  *Optimal value of LP problem* . Isn't this in contrast with the fact that there's no IG? It should mean that the optimal value of LP and ILP should be the same, no?

Please, clarify my doubts.

EDIT:
Michele is very interested in fashion and owns a whole bunch of nice outfits,
collectively forming the set O. A set F of his friends all want to borrow one of Michele’s
outfits to go to a wedding. This should be doable, since |F| ≤ |O|. However, due to different
restrictions like size, body form, or adjustements that have to be made to an outfit to really
look wedding-appropriate, there will be some extra effort w(f, o) ≥ 0 required when any friend
f wants to wear outfit o. Of course, Michele would like to keep the overall effort to a minimum.
a) Model the problem as an integer linear program, and relax this to a corresponding LP.
b) Usually, the optimal solution to a problem’s LP-relaxation is better than that of the original ILP. The factor by which both can differ is called the integrality gap. For Michele’s
problem, there is no such gap and for every fractional LP-solution, there exists an integral
feasible solution with the same cost. Give a polynomial-time algorithm that, from any
given optimal LP-solution, computes such an optimal integer assignmen

Comment: "For every fractional LP-solution, there exists an integral feasible solution with the same cost."

Are you sure about this statement? It should be impossible unless the feasible region is a single point

Comment: The last paragraph is not very well formatted. Can you please edit your question and make it more clear.

Comment: Well I'm sorry more than you because that is exactly what the exercise says, I don't know how to make this more clear, it is all I have. The problem is an assignment one, if this can help you to understand. Given two sets N and M, with |N| <= |M| and a function cost between these, I have to minimize the total cost having all |N| elements matched with some of M.

Comment: do you have a link to the exercise?

Comment: I edited for the complete exercise

Comment: There is no integrality gap iff the LP and ILP have exactly the same optimal value on every instance.

Comment: And so? How should I interpret the exercise? If the LP and ILP have exactly the same optimal value, an hypothetic algorithm what grade of approx could have? I can't understand how to design the algorithm in this case